# Add array as element of another Array

Tags: javascript

I have an array like this

```
$scope.dogs = [
  { id: 1, breed: 'German Shepherd' }, 
  { id: 2, breed: 'Collie' }
]
```

And a second array like this:

```
$scope.owners = [
  { name: 'Mary', breedowned: 'German Shepherd' }, 
  { name: 'Bill', breedowned: 'German Shepherd' }, 
  { name: 'Bob',  breedowned: 'Collie' }
]
```

I want to push the list of owners into the list of dogs like so basically creating:

```
$scope.dogs = [
  { id: 1, breed: 'German Shepherd', owners: [...] }
]
```

I tried to use `forEach` and push the `owners` into the `dogs` array, but it does not work.

```
       angular.forEach($scope.dogs, function (value, key) {

            for (x = 0; x < $scope.owners.length; x++) {
                if ($scope.owners[i].breedowned == value.breed) {
                    $scope.dogs[key].owners.push($scope.owners[i])
                }
            }
    });
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want any form of dependency, just use [Array.prototype.push.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push), this way:

```
Array.prototype.push.apply($scope.owners, $scope.dogs);
```

Comment: Don't think that works though, because that would merge the first array into the second. The asker wants the owners pushed to an owners array on the dog itself.

Comment: that's why i specified "If you don't want any form of dependency". The question was not clear at 100%.

Answer (score 0):

You didnt mention any errors, but I see an issue with you missing `var` in front of the x in the for loop, and also `owners` is not initialized in the dog object. Here's a consistent nested loop solution:

```
angular.forEach($scope.dogs, function (dog) {
    angular.forEach($scope.owners, function (owner) {
        if (owner.breedowned == dog.breed) {
            dog.owners = dog.owners || []
            dog.owners.push(owner)
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: The problem is that I receive the dogs array from a call, so it is not initialized.  If initialized, my original attempt works, but thanks.  I'm going to try your solution.

Comment: Yep that's perfectly okay, just explaining why it likely didnt work :)

Answer (score 0):

Here a better solution that only goes through the owners array once and only through the dogs array once.

```
var tracker = $scope.owners.reduce(function(trackerObj, owner){
   var breedowned = owner.breedowned;
   trackerObj[breedowned] = trackerObj[breedowned] || [];
   trackerObj[breedowned].push(owner);
   return trackerObj;
}, {});
$scope.dogs.forEach(function(dog){
   dog.owners = tracker[dog.breed];
});
```